# Pdf library for android on lgpl license or paid

Tags: android

Could you tell me which library to pdf is the best for android. I would like to know which is good because I want to creat pdf reader. I searching for library on lgpl license or paid library.

Comment: PDFViewer library is good for Read PDF, if you want to example then tell me.

Comment: I need good library with horizontal scrolling, zoom etc and can't be on gpl license

Comment: Horizontal scrolling and zoom in ,zoom out functionality is also available in this library.

Comment: and any cheaper library?

Comment: About my knowledge, this library is free to use.

Comment: Free mean on GPL or LGPL license?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about GPL and LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android

If it is suitable for you it's an Apache 2.0 license library.